# Coldfusion same file different output on CF10 and CF11 using cfheader

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I have this simple code in Coldfusion

```
<cfheader
statuscode="400"
statustext="There was something wrong with the request."
/>

<cfoutput>This is what I want to return as the output.</cfoutput>

<cfabort>
```

When I run this on my localhost running CF10, I get this output on my Chrome browser:
[image]

But when I run this same file on another server running CF11, I get this output:
[image]

Am I missing something? Is there some other way of doing this in CF11?
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a difference in configuration to me. but i'm not familiar with ACF configs.

Comment: What kind of web server do you have in front of this (IIS)?  You might need to configure that web server to allow "pass-through" of the error message(s). I'm guessing your ColdFusion 10 server has this configured but your ColdFusion 11 server does not.

Comment: @Miguel-F yes my local system has coldfusion configured with Apache and the server has it configured with IIS. I forgot to mention that. I will try to configure "pass-through" error messages in IIS. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue actually has nothing to do with ColdFusion, either 10 or 11.
By default, IIS shows not does not show the `statustext` portion of the error message; it only shows the `statuscode` number. This is a security feature to prevent data leakage. If you *do* want to show the `statustext` portion of the error message, that is called "Detailed Error Messages" in IIS.

Steps to enable Detailed Error Messages in IIS 7:

1. Open the IIS7 manager
2. Select the Website and on its features view, double click on "Error Pages".
3. Right click and select the "Edit Feature Settings…" or select the same from the Actions pane (in the right hand side)
4. Select the "Detailed errors" radio button and click on OK
5. Now, even your client browsers will be able to see the detailed error messages.

More information:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers/
- https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis